# Give viewport size to PhantomJS as a command line argument

Tags: phantomjs

Is there a way to specify viewport size for PhantomJS as a command line argument?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```js
var args = require('system').args,
    viewportSize = {width: 1280, height: 1024},
    page = require('webpage').create();

if (args.length >= 1) {
  args.forEach(function(arg, i) {
    if (arg.match(/^[0-9]+x[0-9]+$/)) {
      var viewportParts = arg.split('x');
      viewportSize = {width: viewportParts[0], height: viewportParts[1]};
    }
  });
}
page.viewportSize = viewportSize;
```

Then run your script and add 320x480 after the script name, for example…

Answer (score 1):

Of course. You'll have to process the command line arguments yourself using system.args looking for your custom option of `viewport` or whatever you decide to call it and plucking out its value. Then set page.viewportSize to an appropriate value using the provided argument value.